# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error in running Laravel and Vue

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, laravel-vue

When I use Laravel 10 and vue3, I get the following error when running the local server
What is the cause and how can it be fixed?
Windows 11 and laragon operating system

`This site can’t be reached127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

The page where I used component vue should have been displayed

Comment: Please give more details about the server and url you are requesting.

Comment: laragon localhost : http://127.0.0.1:8000/

npm run dev :

  VITE v5.0.10  ready in 494 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
  ➜  press h + enter to show help

  LARAVEL v10.39.0  plugin v1.0.1

  ➜  APP_URL: http://localhost
7:22:47 AM [vite] page reload resources\views\layouts\app-dashboard.blade.php